# com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException

Tags: environment-variables, s4sdk

Hello I've followed so far the tutorial https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-odata-service-cloud-foundry.html
step by step and I'm having issues, to run the solution on local machine.

I'm running windows 10 and according to tutorial I have set an environment variable to be as following:
`destinations=[{name: "ErpQueryEndpoint", url: "xxxx.s4hana.ondemand.com", username: "INT_USER", password: "xxxxxxxx"}]`

when i run the solution on localhost i get this:

> Message Error occured while handling request: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destinations of provider service instance: Failed to get access token for destination service. If your application is running on Cloud Foundry, make sure to have a binding to both the destination service and the authorization and trust management (xsuaa) service, AND that you either properly secured your application or have set the "ALLOW_MOCKED_AUTH_HEADER" environment variable to true. Please note that authentication types with user propagation, for example, principal propagation or the OAuth2 SAML Bearer flow, require that you secure your application and will not work when using the "ALLOW_MOCKED_AUTH_HEADER" environment variable. If your application is not running on Cloud Foundry, for example, when deploying to a local container, consider declaring the "destinations" environment variable to configure destinations.

Comment: It seems like the the application cannot find the environment variable. Have you restarted your application after adding the environment variable? Besides that, which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Have you used `set` or `export` as command to set the environment variable? Also have you verified that it has been set correctly by trying to echo it after setting?

Comment: I have used set command, yes i have verified the destinations variable and it's look fine, I'm using the latest version of the SDK.

Comment: Okay, can you then verify that the variable is visible by your application? The easiest way is to use `System.getenv("destinations");` before calling the SDK and comparing the returned result.

Comment: i fixed the variable so now is readable from java program, and i get another error: Message Error occured while handling request: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.tenant.exception.TenantNotAvailableException: Failed to get current tenant: tenant not available. For details on the security configuration, please refer to the SAP Cloud Platform documentation. Tutorials on the configuration are available at "https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/SAP_S4HANA_CLOUD_SDK".
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: Good to hear that the first problem was solved. Can you kindly open a new question for the other problem (with a stack trace etc.) and also provide an answer describing what you did to fix the environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the `destinations` variable so it is visible to your application. You can check using `System.getenv("destinations");` in your code.